# Переопределение виртуальных функций при множественном наследовании

Tags: c++, ооп, переопределение, множественное-наследование, виртуальная-функция

```
struct P1 {
    virtual void f() {} // Функция 1
};

struct P2 {
    virtual void f() {} // Функция 2
};

struct D :P1, P2 {
    void f() override {} // Здесь переопределяется функция 1 или функция 2?
};
```

Почему вышеприведённый код не выдаёт ошибку компиляции типа "неоднозначное переопределение"?

Как компилятор определяет, что нужно переопределять в `D`   `P1::f()` или `P2::f()`?

Comment: Тут переопределяется и то, и другое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `D` переопределяет функцию `f`, то какая разница какую именно? `P1::f` или `P2::f`? Ведь у него уже будет своя реализация этой функции. Фиксики запишут в `vtable` новый адрес и всё. Неоднозначности здесь нет. Даже наоборот. Обьявляя `D::f` Вы избавляетесь от неоднозначности.